# Jinja or python to do heavy calculations,which is more ideal and is there a perfomance impact if i choose to do it in Jinja

Tags: python, flask

From time to time ,i am faced with a choice of where to do my for loops and a whole lot other calculations

consider the code below

```
isp_ratings_per_service =     db.session.query(func.count(Service_metric_ratings.ratings_id).label('count_of_users'), \
                                               func.sum(Service_metric_ratings.ratings_id).label('sum_of_ratings'),
                                               Isps.isp_name, Service_metric.metric_name, Services.service_name) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.isp_id == Isps.isp_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.ratings_id == Ratings.ratings_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.metric_id == Service_metric.metric_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.user_id == User.user_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.service_id == Services.service_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric.metric_name == metric_name) \
        .filter(Services.service_name == service_name) \
        .group_by(Isps.isp_name)
```

this for loop below ,will get mne what i want in the flask/python routes

```
 for i in isp_ratings_per_service:
        my_count=i.count_of_users
        my_ratings=i.sum_of_ratings
        isp=i.isp_name
```

And if i want to calculate the average_ratings , it will be

```
my_ratings/my_count
```

and i can pass the result to the jinja templates ....like this with no problem

```
  return render_template('view_average_isp_ratings.html',
                               isp_ratings_per_service=isp_ratings_per_service,
                               count_of_users_who_rated=count_of_users_who_rated,
                               average_isp__service_ratings=average_isp__service_ratings,
                               )
```

My question then follows ,what if i process everything using jinja ...will it slow my application..

Comment: Why don't you try both and profile to see if there's an issue? Depending on how much processing you're doing, it's likely that this time will be irrelevant compared to the networking speeds.

Answer (score 0):

According to Jinja2 [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates), you should minimize logic put into jinja as much as possible. Doing some logic in jinja is fine and makes everything easier, but doing all that in jinja doesn't seem very reasonable.